# Не работает Десериализация XML c#

Tags: c#, xml

Пытаюсь десериализовать XML:

```
    void C()
    {
      var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Activities");
      request.Headers.Clear();
      request.ContentType = "application/xml";
      var document = new XmlDocument();
      var result = new List<Activity>();
      using (Stream stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
      {
         result = (List<Activity>)new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Activity>)).Deserialize(reader);
      }
  }
```

Вот сам класс

```
public class Activity
    {
        [XmlElement("Completed")]
        public bool Completed { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("DueDate")]
        public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ID")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

Вот [тут](https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Activities) можно ознакомится с XML

Вылетает ошибка:

> В документе xml (1, 2) присутствует ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не описали пространство имён.

Попробуйте так:

```
var root = new XmlRootAttribute("ArrayOfActivity")
{
    Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FakeRestAPI.Web.Models"
};
var seri = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Activity>), root);
result = (List<Activity>)seri.Deserialize(s);
```

(и `XmlSerializer` лучше закешировать, а не создавать много раз).